# "dynamic" naming of column in function

Tags: r

I'd like to assign a dynamic name, i.e. the name of the variable I'm passing to the function, as a column name in the dataframe that is being created by the function.

I've tried

```
- deparse(substitute(x))
- toString(x)
```

but no success...

**Code**

```
a <- (1:3)
b <- (5:7)

df <- data.frame(a,b)

fun <- function(x){
  x %>% mutate(c=a+b)
  colnames(x)[3] <- deparse(substitute(x))
  }
```

**Expected behaviour**

after running fun(df):

```
  a b  df
1 1 5  6
2 2 6  8
3 3 7 10
```

instead:

```
> fun(df)
Error in names(x) <- value : 
  'names' attribute [3] must be the same length as the vector [2]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `:=` with evaluation (`!!`)

```
fun <- function(x){
    nm1 <-  deparse(substitute(x))
     x %>% 
        mutate(!! nm1 := a+b)

   }

fun(df)
#  a b df
#1 1 5  6
#2 2 6  8
#3 3 7 10
```

---

In the OP's function, the the output of `x %>% mutate` is not assigned back, therefore, the original dataset have only two columns and not three i.e. if we do

```
fun <- function(x){
   nm1 <- deparse(substitute(x))
    x <- x %>% # assign the output after mutate
            mutate(c=a+b)
   colnames(x)[3] <- nm1
   x # return the dataset
  }   


fun(df)
#  a b df
#1 1 5  6
#2 2 6  8
#3 3 7 10
```